# Find a path from Source to Target in residual graph of a Network flow graph in O(E) time

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow

I am given a flows-network G and their (edge) Capacities and (edge) flows through each edge, and Also a Flow  F. I want to check if there exists a path from source to target in the residual graph in order to find out if F is the maximum flow or not.

Is it possible to do it in O(E) time?

Could someone give me some help to go with, and maybe show I should do it?

- Has been EDITED

Answer (score 0):

> I am given a flows-network G and their (edge) Capacities and (edge) flows through each edge. I want to check if there exists a path from source to target.

If you **only** want to check if there exists a path from source to target, then you don't need residual graph.

> If I had the residual graph then I would just make some adjustments on BFS Algoritm in order to check if there is such path, easy. I found this could be done in O(|E|).

Time complexity of BFS algorithm is `O(V+E)`, not `O(E)`.

> However I don't have the residual graph so my question is if should compute it first and then proceed, and if so, will it increase my overall time complexity O(|E|)?

Computing residual graph should require more time than `O(V+E)`.

If you trying to solve the [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem), why don't you use standard algorithms like [ford-fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) whose time complexity is `O(E max|f|)`?

---

**Update**

> I want to check if there exists a path from source to target in the residual graph in order to find out if F is the maximum flow or not. Is it possible to do it in O(E) time?

To check if there is a path between two nodes in a directed graph, you should need `O(V+E)` time. You can use either BFS or DFS as you mentioned before in your question.

Comment: really sorry so bad formulated question @Wasi Ahmad , i have edited it

Comment: I believe BFS is O(|E|) in a connected graph ? @Wasi Ahmad

Comment: @J.doe no, for BFS, it is `O(V+E)`. please look into the algorithm from any source in web. if the graph is not connected, anyway, you cannot apply BFS in that graph!

Comment: Any suggestion on what approach i could take to find out if there is a path from source to target in  a residual graph - in order to find out if the given Flow is maximum? Considering it could be done in O(|E) ?@Wasi Ahmad

Comment: frankly speaking, I don't know whether the max flow problem can be solved in O(E)!!! But my suggestion is to use `ford-fulkerson` algorithm.

Comment: I meant if I had a given flow  , and I wanted to check if it is the max flow, then I would only need to check if there is a Path from source to target in the residual graph, is it possible to do it in O(E)?  I think i just formulated the question so bad from start so that i confused you a bit. @Wasi Ahmad

Comment: @J.doe No, i don't think its possible because to find a path between source and target in a graph, you need `O(V+E)`. You can use either BFS or DFS but you should need `O(V+E)`.

Answer (score 0):

BFS could be used to find a path in the residual graph. Running BFS requires O(|E|+|V|) running time. In flow network, all vertex are connected, thus, number of vertex is no greater than double of the number of edges. With this information, running BFS to find a path in the residual graph is with complexity O(|E|)